# How to handle links for guest user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On every page we have a condition like this for guest user.

```
<% if not_guest? %> 
<% link_to "show", path %>
<% end %>

<% if not_guest? %> 
<% link_to "delete", path %>
<% end %>

<% if not_guest? %> 
<% link_to "edit", path %>
<% end %>
```

for which link should appear or not for guest user.

Are there any better ways to handle this scenario instead of writing the conditions for every link ?

Comment: You may also be interested in looking at an authorization gem like cancan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), which comes with it's own helpers similar to the conditional statements you have above

Comment: You might want to check out link_to_if or link_to_unless Url helpers Rails provides to do similar things. ApiDock: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a helper:

```
#helpers/application_helper.rb
def link_to_unless_guest(*args)
  if not_guest
    link_to(*args)
  end
end
```

Then call like

```
<% link_to_unless_guest "show", path %>
```

Comment: Thank you. One problem with it. If I have link like this <li> <% link_to_unless_guest "show", path %> </li> than this will distort my layout. Any Solution ?

Comment: @krunal-shah Modify the helper so it wraps the `link_to` within `<li>`. Then you don't end up with empty list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def link_to_editable(*args)
    options = args.extract_options![:parent]
    html_tag = options.nil? ? nil : options.delete(:html_tag)
    if not_guest
      unless html_tag.nil?
        content_tag html_tag,options do
          link_to(*args)
        end
      else
        link_to(*args)
      end
    end
  end

<%= link_to_editable 'Show', path,:parent => {:html_tag => "li",:style => "border-top:1px solid #A2A2A2;",:class => "left"} %>

<%= link_to_editable 'Show', path %>
```

Modified helper which is provided by @Max as per my need.